# Zedgraph, more than one bar

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, zedgraph

I'm trying to make a stackedbar with zedgraph. I've used some coded example founded in a question on this site. I'v made some changes, but I can't get i to work as I want. The output on the chart are bars stacked over each other. And when the method are runs second time, the bars from the first time are still there, and the new ones are built on top of the old bars.

The wanted output: I want to see a stackedbar for every integer I have in my list. But it must be such that the first integer in listA is on the same bar as the first from listB.

```
        zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();
        zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.GraphObjList.Clear();
        //I want to clear my chart, and write a new one. I dont think the above works??^^^

        GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

        myPane.BarSettings.Type = BarType.PercentStack;
        myPane.XAxis.Type = ZedGraph.AxisType.Date;

        PointPairList PPLa = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList PPLb = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList PPLc = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList PPLd = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList PPLf = new PointPairList();
        List<int> listA = new List<int>();
        List<int> listB = new List<int>();
        List<int> listC = new List<int>();
        List<int> listD = new List<int>();
        List<int> listF = new List<int>();
        listA = getIntA()
        listB = getIntB()
        listC = getIntC()
        listD = getIntD()
        listF = getIntF()

        int Max = listA.Count;
        //^^ I've made this line to control how many times the loop should run.

        for (int i = 0; i < Max; i++)
        {
            DateTime dtime = DateTime.Now;
            double date = (double)new XDate(dtime);

            int som1;
            for(som1 = 0; som1 <= (listA.Count - 1); som1++)
            {
                int a = listA[i];
                PPLa.Add(date, (double)a);

            }

            int som2;
            for (som2 = 0; som2 <= (listB.Count - 1); som2++)
            {
                int b = listB[i];
                PPLb.Add(date, (double)b);

            }

            int som3;
            for (som3 = 0; som3 <= (listC.Count - 1); som3++)
            {
                int c = listC[i];
                PPLc.Add(date, (double)c);

            }

            int som4;
            for (som4 = 0; som4 <= (listD.Count - 1); som4++)
            {
                int d = listD[i];
                PPLd.Add(date, (double)d);

            }

            int som5;
            for (som5 = 0; som5 <= (listF.Count - 1); som5++)
            {
                int f = listF[i];
                PPLf.Add(date, (double)f);

            }



            BarItem myBara = myPane.AddBar("A", PPLa, Color.Red);
            BarItem myBarb = myPane.AddBar("B", PPLb, Color.Blue);
            BarItem myBarc = myPane.AddBar("C", PPLc, Color.Gray);
            BarItem myBard = myPane.AddBar("D", PPLd, Color.Black);
            BarItem myBarf = myPane.AddBar("F", PPLf, Color.Pink);


            zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();



        }
        zg1.AxisChange();
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: take a look at this site: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx

Comment: I've looked at this site before, but I couldnt find anything of use - I think :)

Comment: ive looked into it and found what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void graph2()
    {
        zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();
        zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.GraphObjList.Clear();
        // clearing not tested

        GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

        myPane.BarSettings.Type = BarType.PercentStack;
        //      myPane.XAxis.Type = ZedGraph.AxisType.Date;
        // Date wont work in our case

        PointPairList PPLa = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList PPLb = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList PPLc = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList PPLd = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList PPLf = new PointPairList();
        List<int> listA = new List<int>();
        List<int> listB = new List<int>();
        List<int> listC = new List<int>();
        List<int> listD = new List<int>();
        List<int> listF = new List<int>();
        //listA = getIntA();
        //listB = getIntB();
        //listC = getIntC();
        //listD = getIntD();
        //listF = getIntF();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            listA.Add(i);
            listB.Add(i + 1);
            listC.Add(i);
        }
        // above is used to fill up the lists (for example)
        // be aware that listA[0] = 0 for i = 1, (will be vissible in chart)


        // when you us < instead of <= you dont need a listA.Count - 1
        // below is not failsafe, if any list is smaller than listA an error may appear
        // this is just a sample so i thought it wouldnt matter
        for (int i = 0; i < listA.Count; i++)
        {
            PPLa.Add(i, (double)listA[i]);
            PPLb.Add(i, (double)listB[i]);
            PPLc.Add(i, (double)listC[i]);
            PPLd.Add(i, (double)listA[i]);
            PPLf.Add(i, (double)listB[i]);
        }

        // dragged drawing baritems out of forloop
        BarItem myBara = myPane.AddBar("A", PPLa, Color.Red);
        BarItem myBarb = myPane.AddBar("B", PPLb, Color.Blue);
        BarItem myBarc = myPane.AddBar("C", PPLc, Color.Gray);
        BarItem myBard = myPane.AddBar("D", PPLd, Color.Black);
        BarItem myBarf = myPane.AddBar("F", PPLf, Color.Pink);

        zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The (one) Zedgraph project I did, I always did something like:

```
master = zedGraphDruck.MasterPane;
master.GraphObjList.Clear();
master.PaneList.Clear();
GraphPane g = new GraphPane(gpr, titel, null, null);
...
master.Add(g);
zedGraphDruck.AxisChange();
zedGraphDruck.Invalidate();
```

with gpr being a (new) Rectangle with the required size and title a string;